# Run javascript after mobile 'back' press

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, mobile

We have a mobile site (ASP.NET in MVC style) which, among other things, displays a fullscreen HTML slideshow.

To display this, we run code on the mobileHTMLMovie view like so:

```
$( function() {
    $(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $("header").hide();
    $(".subHeader").hide();
    $(".subHeaderAccent").hide();
    $("footer").hide();
    $(".ui-content").css("width", "100%").css("height", "100%").css("margin","0").css("background-color", "#000");
    });
});
```

The problem we're seeing is that when the user pushes the 'back' button (s/he's limited to the hardware controls, as this code disables all the wrapper elements, including our HTML movement buttons) the elements remain hidden.

I have been unable to find a way to run the 'reversal' code (show instead of hide, removing the style attribute from ".ui-content") on the page they land on.  The page they land on doesn't run document.ready when they arrive, the movie page doesn't run 'onunload' or 'onbeforeunload', and the other suggestion I've found online (.live('click') on the '[data-rel=back]' element) hasn't worked either.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: @mplungjan: Hardly - I can always have a timed event set up to constantly check if those are visible and switch them back on if they aren't.  It's just hackish and ugly - I'd rather have it reliably fired when they land.

Comment: can you add the show to the end of the page?

Comment: Can you add an expiration to the page (so it doesn't cache) so that when they nav back it gets a new page from the server?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to use the History object and bind to the `popstate` event? Basically, when the slideshow is displayed, you would push a new state in, and then when the user presses back, it might trigger the pop.

**Example:**

```
$(function() {
    $(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
        $("header").hide();
        $(".subHeader").hide();
        $(".subHeaderAccent").hide();
        $("footer").hide();
        $(".ui-content").css("width", "100%").css("height", "100%").css("margin","0").css("background-color", "#000");

        window.history.replaceState("slideshow", "Slideshow", "slideshow");
    });

    window.addEventListener('onpopstate', function(event) {
        if (event.state === "slideshow") {
            //Close the slideshow
        }
    }
});
```

I'm not sure what the flow is for the page, but you'd either use `replaceState` or `pushState` depending on how the slideshow is launched

**Resources**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history